# XSLT 1.0: Passing _all_ parameters in 'pass-through' template (ie tunneling)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

<del>Please forgive the poor nomenclature in this, probably why I'm struggling to google an answer.</del>

Basically I am asking if parameter tunneling from xslt 2.0 has any analogue in 1.0, or if there is a clever way to get 'some way there'.  I'm using msxsl

Suppose I have a template like so:

```
<xsl:template name="outer">
   <xsl:apply-templates>
       <xsl:with-param name="x" select="y"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

If the apply-templates call gets picked up directly by a template that knows about the parameter then all is good, but suppose we have some general templates to ignore certain elements and process their children:

```
<xsl:template match="tag_to_ignore">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

if these are 'hit' OR when the tag_to_ignore is not explicitly matched and XSLT does its default apply templates to children behaviour

the parameters are 'lost'

is there anyway to tell a template to 'accept' all parameters it was passed and pass them down?

(ie the real code there are many, many, params that could come in and potentially need to be passed out, trying to avoid a maintenance issue of having to accept every possible para and explicitly pass it on)

Comment: To my knowledge a template must be explicitly informed of the params to expect.

Comment: you could wrap all your parameters as xml nodes in a variable and pass that instead of defining and passing multiple parameters to your templates.

Comment: It's pity, you're stuck with XSLT 1.0, in XSLT 2.0 they're the attribute @tunnel in bot xsl:param and xsl:with-param which give you the exact behaviour you're looking for... With no way to upgrade your XSLT proc, wrap param in variable or explicitly pass all of them in each template seems to be the only ways you got...

Comment: @gp I had considered that option but that has its own maintenance issues with us then having to have comments etc to describe what params that template 'actually' expects and code to rebuild the paraNode to pass on.

Comment: I would second the suggestion made by @gp. I am not sure you understood it fully - I certainly didn't understand the objections you have raised against it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - Well it's not ideal xsl, but we have a fair number of items which do (Take 6 params, do one thing, pass 5 down to other template after changing the value of one) so there would be some extra 'code noise' manipulating the 'parameter node'.  Also at present say a template takes params 'color, size, shape' then that's fairly self documenting where as if everything took 'paramNode' then we'd lose IDE support for parameter correctness and have to have lots of 'this actually takes params x,y,z' comments.  Or am I really missing something?

Comment: It seems to me it's just a matter of replacing a set of key/value pairs (individual parameters), with a single parameter that carries the same set of key/value pairs as its internal value. If you would start each template by "off-loading" the required parameters to "local" parameters, I believe that would be self-commenting enough. Yes, there is *some* extra coding involved, but unless you upgrade to an XSLT 2.0 processor, it's either that or explicit individual parameter send/receive/pass-through (which IMHO is not an option to be dismissed either).

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes this would not be much noiser than normal xsl paramater passing/receiving really I guess, will think on it.  Defaulting will be more verbose of course, but don't think there is much of that going on in the relevant code sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 you can use [tunnel parameters](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#tunnel-params) but in XSLT 1.0 there is no such feature.

Comment: Thank you for the magic word 'tunnel'!  Assuming no-one else comes up with a clever trick I'll accept this as the answer.  Oh for 2.0!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I had a similar issue before I heard about tunnelling parameters and solved it by adding the same parameters to the one-off template, then passing it back out in that apply-templates.  For instance, in your case

```
<xsl:template match="tag_to_ignore">
    <xsl:param name="x"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="x" select="$x" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

I *THINK* this will work in XSLT 1.0, but I'm fairly new to all this myself.